# How to filter Objects in Nunjucks?

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine, nunjucks

I am a newbee in Node.js development and trying to figure out how to reach a clean way to list records in a page with Nunjucks template .

So, when rendering my nunjucks page receive two objects
One of them is a Brand listing like

```
    [
  { BrandId: 4, BrandName: 'Fiat' },
  { BrandId: 5, BrandName: 'Mercedes' },
  { BrandId: 6, BrandName: 'BMW' },
  { BrandId: 7, BrandName: 'Chevrolet' },
  { BrandId: 8, BrandName: 'Jaguar' },
  { BrandId: 9, BrandName: 'Toyota' },
  { BrandId: 10, BrandName: 'Renault' },
  { BrandId: 11, BrandName: 'Peugeot ' }
]
```

Another object is called services and to build the page i use a for loop to list services properties .

```
 {% for service in services %}
             
               <tr>
                 <td>{{service.ServiceId}}</td>
                 <td>{{service.ServiceName}}</td>
                 <td>{{service.BrandId}} </td>  
                 <td>{{service.VehicleName}}</td>
                 <td>{{service.ServicePrice}}</td>
                 <td>
```

As you can See... I have BrandId in my services object ... so what I would like is recover the BrandName from brands object that I have ...

I have tried apply selectattr filter ... but do not seems to work
Do you have any idea on how I can acomplish that ?
thanks in advance